# Visual Studio 2015 does not display Errors List window

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I'm running Visual Studio 2015 Preview on my machine, and no matter what I try I cannot view the "Errors List" window. I have done the following to try to make the window open:

- Try to open the window from the "View" menu
- Build a project with errors, with the errors window set to auto-display
- Repair the VS 2015 installation
- Open a different solution
- Try to open the window with no solution loaded

I am assuming that this is a bug in the preview version that I am running (14.0.22310.1 DP), but was wondering if there is perhaps a solution that I could try in the meantime to make this work.

Comment: Try cleaning the temp folder, delete this registry key: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0`, and `C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0` (ps, the username & version will be different)

Comment: @ChrisEelmaa - Thanks for the idea, but no luck unfortunately :/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I submitted this problem as a bug on Microsoft Connect (https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1074514/error-list-has-disappeared). The ensuing response solved the issue:

> Looking at the data you've provided, I believe you may have hit a
>   known issue with the new Error List in Visual Studio 2015 Preview,
>   which manifests itself when you attempt to double-click at the edge of
>   a column to resize. The resize works, but the next time you restart
>   Visual Studio the error list fails to load.
>
> If you see this problem again, it’s possible to work around it to get
>   your error list back up and running again. This requires editing the
>   registry (which should always be undertaken with caution, after
>   backing up the registry)
>
> The relevant key is
>   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\NewTaskList
>
> Follow these steps:
>
> 1. Close all running copies of Visual Studio on the affected machine
> 2. Open RegEdit and locate the relevant key
> 3. Delete the whole key (it will be regenerated when Visual Studio 2015 Preview re-starts)
> 4. Re-start Visual Studio 2015, and the Error List should be available again
>
> We have fixed the underlying bug in later builds - watch for new
>   releases of Visual Studio 2015. Thanks for taking the time to try
>   Visual Studio 2015 Preview

Comment: I uninstalled the ErrorList extension to fix it but couldn't find the extension in search any more.  Than found this answer :(  Any idea about how to re-install ErrorList extension?  Thx in advance

Comment: This is the correct answer according to Microsoft. No extension is needed. This *only* applies to the current (as of writing) preview version of Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: I hear you but in my case I deleted a new extension which came with VS2015 Preview called ErrorList and it removes new features of Error/Task Lists which fixes the issue too.  (it removes new Error/Task Lists features of vs2015p) but can't re-load again.  anyway I thought you may know it.  thx for the reply

Comment: I just resolved this issue with the above detailed steps on the following version:

Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2015 Preview
Version 14.0.22310.1 DP

Comment: still a problem for me even in RTM version (may be different fix)

Comment: This also fixed my Visual Studio 2015, version 14 update 1.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with VS 2013. Levi's answer was helpful. I found a registry path `\\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ErrorList` and a key of **ErrorListScopeFilteringActive**.  This was set to 1. I changed it to 0 and it solved the problem.  (I closed Visual Studio and came back in.)

Comment: I don't see "12.0" for Visual Studio 2015 installation. I looked under "14.0", but could not find `ErrorList` as key or value. I tried to find out `ErrorListScopeFilteringActive` but couldn't find it anywhere

Answer (score 1):

Mine oddly came back when I switched from framework 4.5 to 4.6 for my project.

Coincidence or not I'll never know... (unless people upvote / downvote this)

Be warned though: Make sure you have checked in any changes first because changing the framework version triggered all my service references to be re-fetched which isn't always desirable. Doing so will allow you then to approve exactly what it changed.

Answer (score 1):

I also had almost similar issue on VS2015 where it said there were errors but it did not display them on the error list, in my case there was absolutely nothing wrong with the IDE just that I somehow told it to display only errors on the current document , my solution was, change the document on the error list from "current document" to "Entire Solution", please see screenshot[Changing error display on Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1R4yD.png)

Comment: It doesn't help either!

Answer (score 0):

`Window -> Reset Window Layout` worked for me. Also, the error window was visible in fullscreen mode `View -> Fullscreen`

Answer (score -2):

open tools>>options>>general>>(search for the word errors)>>Always show errors while debugging... DONE!!

Comment: This was a bug in the preview version mentioned in the question and was only resolvable with the registry hack mentioned in my answer.